# Submit iOS app to app store on behalf of the team

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, developer-program

Me and my friend have developed an iOS app and we want to release it on App Store. Apple offers an Individual or Enterprise developer account which costs 199$. The problem is that we are not a legit company of any kind and we don't want to have any documents or registration. We jut want it to appear in App Store under our team name. An individual account is also not an option as we want us both to be mentioned as developers or none of us (just a team name). Is there a way to do it?

Comment: My recommendation would be to contact apple https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit/

Comment: In any shared enterprise it is probably a good idea to set up a legal structure here a company to deal with the issues when something goes wrong

Comment: @Mark yeah, but it is just a simple non-commercial side project. Why bother setting anything up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple used to allow an "Artist Name" that would allow any unique name to be the developer that appeared on the App Store. Now "if you are an individual or sole proprietor/single person business, your personal legal name will be listed as the seller on the App Store." (from [Apple Developer Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/enrollment/)). Apple will also not allow any "DBAs, Fictitious Businesses, Trade names, or branches" to be registered under an organization/enterprise account. If you want your name as the developer, register as a company (which is not too hard to do) and use that name and the information of your company when opening a developer account. Then, you can open free developer accounts that can work inside that organization on iTunes Connect. If you and your friend are both under 18 and you do not want to create a company, the account must be registered under a parent or guardian's name. Then free developer accounts for you and your friend can be added. If you and/or your friend are over 18 you would have to use your name. Apple Developer Accounts only cost 99 USD/year now.

Comment: Thanks, it's actually "Artist Name" what I was looking for. We do not need anything more than that.

Comment: Apple does not allow using artist names for apps anymore, so you're out of luck as I described in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no way to do that. You'll have to either create a company (which is quite easy most places) - or use one of your names with Apple. You can mention both your names in the description of your app if you want to.

Most users probably couldn't care less who created the apps they're using. So in practice it is normally not a big deal to be listed as the developer or not.